# What is idiom or proverb that is used to indicate 'the abuse of authority or money by foolish persons'

Tags: idiom-requests, proverb-requests

When a foolish person gains wealth suddenly, s/he might start to spend it ostentatiously and sometimes even talks rubbish. If such people get a powerful position, they might even abuse it foolishly. Such persons need not necessarily be evil ones, but the results could be because of their foolishness.

There are a few proverbs in Telugu language which translates to when a poor person became rich all of a sudden, he asked the barber to dress his hair at midnight.

To take one a peg lower - does this convey the appropriate meaning?
What are the other English equivalent proverbs or idioms for the same?

Comment: The question title and body text are asking different things. Are you looking to describe a change in someone's character due to newfound power, or newfound wealth?

Comment: @NuclearWang I have edited both the title and the body. Yes, I am referring to the change but their actions are a result of their foolishness and not necessarily because of the pride.

Comment: penny wise, pound foolish?

Comment: All that money seemed to go to his head.

Comment: [***Upstart, parvenu, nouveau riche**?*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/parvenu) It's not clear to me the matter of your "foolish person" getting *money* is necessarily relevant. What you seem to be talking about is people who [***get ideas above their station***](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/above-ones-station.2941900/), whether this is connected to unmerited sudden wealth, or to equally bizarre "elevation", such as [***Forrest Gump's***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/) meteoric rise from obscurity.

Answer (score 3):

There is an old saying **A fool and his money are quickly parted***.

It dates from at least as early as the sixteenth century.

Thomas Tusser, in his rhyme *Five Hundreth Pointes of Good Husbandrie* (1573) says:

*A foole & his money, 
 be soone at debate: 
 which after with sorow, 
 repents him to late.*

And more exactly to the point:

Dr. John Bridges, in *Defence of the Government of the Church of England* (1587) says:

*If they pay a penie or two pence more for the reddinesse of them..let them looke to that, a foole and his money is soone parted*.

Quotations from [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-fool-and-his-money-are-soon-parted.html)

Comment: _Parted_? I'm sensing a theme here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your comments Edwin remind me of cryptic clues. I never seem to get them. Unless it has to do with [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408852/your-fly-is-open-you-mean-my-flies/408859#408859)

Comment: Look at Prov 21:5b below. And [the translation of] the original proverbs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well I'll upvote your answer, but your comment remains as cryptic as ever.

Comment: when a poor person became rich all of a sudden, he asked the barber to dress his hair at midnight. // quickly parted // hasty short cuts (sorry, shortcuts)

Answer (score 3):

Proverbs 13:11 [English Standard Version: BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/esv/proverbs/13-11.htm) has

> Wealth gained hastily will dwindle, but whoever gathers little by
>   little will increase it.

And I feel I have to include Proverbs 21:5 
[New Living Translation: BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/proverbs/21-5.htm)

> Good planning and hard work lead to prosperity, but hasty shortcuts
>   lead to poverty.

Answer (score 0):

> **spend money like a drunken sailor**: to spend large amounts of money frivolously.
>
> **pour money down the drain**: to waste money on something useless
>
> (a less nice saying that means the same thing: **piss money up the
> wall**)
>
> **wear a ten-dollar hat on a five-cent head**: to be rich but stupid
>
> **more money than sense**: same as above, with the implication that the person doesn't know how to spend the money sensibly.
>
> **money talks and bullshit walks**: a rich person can get away with anything, or make others do their bidding, no matter how bad.

References:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/money+talks+and+bullshit+walks  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piss+money+up+the+wall  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pour+money+down+the+drain  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/He+wears+a+ten-dollar+hat+on+a+five-cent+head
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spend+money+like+a+drunken+sailor
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-more-money-than-sense